# How to paginate inside a tab?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, filter, pagination

I used UI Bootstrap pagination and it works perfectly on its own. However, when I add tabs (using `ul li` and `ng-show`), pagination no longer works. Note that I also use `filter` (in Angular) on the content that I want to paginate.

Here is my code -- also on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efaLj8a0/

```
<ul ng-init="tabQ = 1">
  <li ng-class="{active:tabQ===1}">
    <a href ng-click="tabQ = 1">Newest</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active:tabQ===2}">
    <a href ng-click="tabQ = 2">Hottest</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="tabQ === 1">
    <ul class="striped-list">
        <li ng-repeat="question in questions | startFrom:begin | limitTo:itemsPerPage | filter:orderProp">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<pagination total-items="totalItems" page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" direction-links="false" rotate="false" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" on-page-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

In `controller.js`:

```
$scope.itemsPerPage = 15;    
$scope.$watch('questions.length', function(length) {
  if(length) {
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.questions.length;
  }
});
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
$scope.$watch('currentPage', function(pageChanged) {
  $scope.begin = ($scope.currentPage-1)*$scope.itemsPerPage;
});
```

Comment: Post a sample to jsfiddle showing the problem, you'll get better traction from people to answer then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just updated the post with a JSFiddle link

Comment: Just updated your fiddle with one that works: http://jsfiddle.net/efaLj8a0/2/; could not get your filters to function so omitted them.  Given this updated example, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for updating my fiddle. I added my custom filter startFrom, which indicates the starting item from which pagination will begin, but I could not get it to work on Angular 1.2 (the newest one on JSFiddle - mine is 1.3). 

Anyhow, my goal is to paginate within the tab. For example, when users click on Newest, the list of questions will paginate itself accordingly. Likewise with the tab Hottest if there is list of questions there. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efaLj8a0/3/ I originally used UI bootstrap, that's why i included its cnd in the first place